# Getting error 10054 and 10053 when trying to upload to Amazon S3 using MultiPart uploads, with CloudAPI in C++Builder XE5

Tags: delphi, amazon-s3, c++builder, winsock, vcl

I've been trying to use the Amazon S3 multipart upload technique without luck, using the CloudAPI functions included in C++Builder XE5.

When calling `TAmazonStorageService.UploadPart` I always get, after a little pause (maybe what it takes to send the bytes), a socket error 10054 or 10053. I have tried with HTTP and HTTPS, with no difference.

I can get correctly the UploadId using the `TAmazonStorageService.InitiateMultipartUpload`, and uploading using the UploadObject works fine, so apparently the connection and setup is working fine, but something with this calls produces the socket error.

Any idea of where to look? I haven't found examples of Mutlipart uploads with this CloudAPI: the ones I've seen are for a single-part-upload (which works fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10054 (aka "[connection reset by peer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)") could mean that the remote host was not happy with the data sent from the client side and "pulled the plug".

> This normally results if (... ... ...) the remote host uses a hard close. 
>   This error may also result if a connection was broken due to
>   keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations
>   are in progress.

10053 is a similar problem - and might also be caused by a protocol error in the data sent from the client:

> An established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   computer, possibly due to a data transmission time-out or protocol
>   error.

Two suggestions to narrow down the problem source:

- insert a HTTP proxy (Fiddler2 for example) to capture and view the HTTP traffic, or - if the library is based on Indy - use a Indy Interceptor component to log the HTTP data
- use a working client implementation written in a different language (C# for example) to verify that multipart works with your specific configuration, and if it works, compare its HTTP communication with the HTTP communication in the Delphi version

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestion of Fiddler2 or the Indy Interceptor.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @mjn - using Fiddler I was able to see that there were several problems with the requests, that for some reason didn't get to the client app but Indy swallowed them, or something like that, and just returned the 10054 error.

Comment: I just now need to figure out why it returns a SignatureDoesNotMatch when passing the MD5 for each part. Without it it works fine.